# Question about 単独

Tags: meaning, words

Does word 単独 has some figurative meaning close to something like "not ready"?
I'm asking because it used in this sentence

> だがそれは、俺が“単独”だった場合だ。

But protagonist definitely isn't "solo", since he has companion, but he is worried what can happen if he "disarm" himself and something bad happens. So it should be something close to "not ready" from context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

> だがそれは、俺が“単独”だった場合だ。

means something along the line of: "But that would only be the case if I was (still) alone."

So he is worried about what might have happened with him in this situation while he was still travelling/fighting (?) solo. I guess he recently banded together with his companion?

In that sense the normal sole/single/solo translation would be correct.